# run ubuntu img from console on qemu

Tags: qemu

I created vdi img first 

$sudo qemu-img create -f vdi ubuntu-server.vdi 10G

and installed ubuntu server

$sudo qemu-system-x86_64 -m 4G -hda ubuntu-server.vdi -cdrom ubuntu-16.04.3-server-amd64.iso -boot d

However, I want to run this ubuntu img without gui.(only console) 

I searched about this, but usually people boot kernel img (-kernel bzimage) with append option(console=ttyS0). This option is used with -kernel option.

so when I tried 

$qemu -hda ubuntu-server.vdi -m 1G -append "~~~"

 that option cannot be used without -kernel option. I tried nographic, curses options, but the result is just not to display. is there any command or option to use console instead of gui when using run ubuntu?